# Meteor: Manually trigger cursor.observeChanges() events

Tags: meteor

The way my app is structured, I need to run some setup code every time a property in a document collection is changed, including checking that property when a new document is added, and initially for existing documents. Here is some example pseudo-code:

```
Stuff.find().observeChanges({
    added: runUpdate,
    changed: runUpdate
});

runUpdate = function (id, fields) {
  if fields.is_active {
    // Run setup code
  } else {
    // Run teardown code
  }
}
```

This setup works great for modifying existing documents and creating new ones, because it provides a central trigger. Unfortunately though, there is no guarantee that the `added` will fire initially for all existing documents.

Is there any way to "invalidate" the collection when the template is rendered so that the `added` callback is fired, or a way to manually trigger `added` for a collection, similar to how you can trigger jQuery events using `$('.foo').trigger('click')`

Comment: It makes sense that `added` would not always be triggered, because the template rendering and the state of your subscription may have nothing to do with each other. Can you say in a lot more detail what you are trying to accomplish by doing this? I ask because usually when I see code like this on the client, the answer ends up being a misunderstand about the way meteor works.

Comment: Hey David, I actually have a pretty decent understanding of how Meteor works. I updated my questions to be a bit more clear about *why* I want `added` to trigger initially. It could be that this isn't the best design pattern for accomplishing this, but it seems like a pretty great & natural fit if I can figure out how to manually trigger `added` on existing documents.